# Windows10 flat Theme not applied when app runs as a service

Tags: c#, windows, service

The following piece of code instantiates a UserControl containing some standard controls and renders its content to a png

```cs
public void TrySavingUiAsPng()
{
    // tried with and without this two lines, no differences
    //System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    //System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    var control = new MyTestUserControl();
    
    using (var bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(300, 200))
    {
        control.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
        bmp.Save(tempFileName);
    }
}
```

On a windows10 machine (windows 10 enterprise 21H2), when done interactively, the ui has the classic flat theme, and the generated png looks like this:

[image: running the test locally]

The problem I'm having is that if the same code runs as a service (therefore presumably in session 0), the ui looks '3d', xp-style, as if the flat windows theme had not been applied. the png generated by the service looks like this:

[image: running as service]

Question: is there a way to make sure that, when run as as a service, the controls have the standard windows10 flat theme?

notes

- I don't want to interact with the ui. the ultimate goal is to just generate a png of the ui
- above example is winforms, but the same problem occurs with wpf and most likely standard win32 controls

what I have tried, but failed

- marked the service as 'Allow service to interact with desktop'
- use a user instead of the LocalSystem account
- verified that the 'Themes' service is running

Comment: Perhaps ADA settings (also called “ease of access” in windows)?

Comment: I checked but there is nothing in Ease of Access settings that changes the windows theme

Comment: "the same problem occurs with wpf" -- WPF doesn't use standard control rendering, it's all custom rendered in D3D. So what exactly do you mean here?

Comment: @Blindy in wpf the same problem occurs in the sense that buttons, scrollbars, combos etc have a 3d border. I can post a picture but it's the same thing. in this case I guess that for some reason the Classic.xaml (xp) resource is loaded instead of Aero.xaml

Answer (score 0):

maybe the answer is in [this microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/hardware/design/dn653293(v=vs.85))

> Because Session 0 is no longer a user session, services that are
> running in Session 0 do not have access to the video driver. This
> means that any attempt that a service makes to render graphics fails

without a gpu and therefore without graphics acceleration the system scales to an old theme. it's just a theory, the documentation is extremely poor.